# при обучении по Шилдту (непонятен нюанс)

Tags: java, конструктор

код ниже работает все отлично-непонятно другое
int miles мы не задавали значений (расстояния) а задали их int dist = 252;
По идее же тут вместо miles должно быть dist непонятно как он производит расчет если у miles нет значений

> double fuelneeded(int miles) {
>           return (double) miles/mpg;
>   по идее dist\mpg=252\21 или 12 и получается 12 и 21 как при выводе

*Заранее благодарен всем откликнувшимся!*

```
//добавление конструктора
class Vehicle {
    int passengers;//количество пассажиров
    int fuelcap;//емкость топливного бака
    int mpg;//потребление топлива в милях на галлон

    //это конструктор класса Vehicle
    Vehicle(int p, int f, int m) {
        passengers = p;
        fuelcap = f;
        mpg = m;
    }
    //определить дальность поездки ТС
    int range() {
        return mpg * fuelcap;
    }
    //рассчитать объем топлива необходимого ТС для преодоления заданного расстояния
    double fuelneeded(int miles) {
        return (double) miles/mpg;
    }
}

public class VehConsDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //полностью сконструировать объекты транспортных средств
        Vehicle minivan = new Vehicle(7,16,21);
        Vehicle sportscar = new Vehicle(2,14,12);
        double gallons;
        int dist = 252;

        gallons = minivan.fuelneeded(dist);

        System.out.println("Для преодоления "+dist+" миль минивэну требуется"+ gallons+" галлонов топлива");

        gallons = sportscar.fuelneeded(dist);

        System.out.println("Для преодоления "+dist+" миль спорткару требуется"+ gallons+" галлонов топлива");
    }
}
```

> Для преодоления 252 миль минивэну требуется 12.0 галлонов топлива Для
>   преодоления 252 миль спорткару требуется 21.0 галлонов топлива

Answer (score 0):

miles - это аргумент метода `fuelneeded()`, переменная примет то значение, которое ей будет передано при вызове метода (в коде miles = dist).

Если бы вместо dist (`fuelneeded(dist)`) , метод вызывали с аргументом 5 (`fuelneeded(5)`) , то miles было бы равно 5

**update**

Аргументы в методах нужны для того, чтобы один и тот же метод мог производить операции с разными значениями (в данном случае рассчитывать сколько нужно бензина для любого указанного расстояния). Иначе потребовалось бы множество практически одинаковых методов.

Какую бы переменную или даже натуральное число не передали в метод, этот метод знает, что с ней делать и как посчитать результат, потому что внутри метода любое переданное ему значение всегда фигурирует как miles (имя переменной-аргумента в сигнатуре этого метода)

так же смотрите ответы на [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/977877/177345)

Comment: Спасибо большое, точно увидел. Непонятно только зачем так заморочено, если у нас 2 объекта минивен и спорткар а расстояние которое к ним относится одинаковое =252, можнож было в конструкторе написать miles=252 и сразу обратится fuelneeded(miles) ?

Comment: Не заморочено, а просто и удобно. Если в конструкторе написать 252, а потом понадобится считать доя другого расстояния, то что делать?

Comment: имя переданной методу переменной никак не влияет на имя самой переменной метода, вы можете назвать ее как вам угодно, при вызове метода произойдет следующее: значение переменной переданной в метод (в вашем случае это dist) будет присвоено переменой-аргументу метода (в вашем случае это miles), как бы вы не называли переменную dist, даже таким же именем miles, произойдет одно и то же, только в последнем случае имена переменной класса и переменной метода будут одинаковы, но это будут разные переменные. и у методов не конструкторы, а сигнатура. конструкторы у классов

Comment: Все понятно.Спасибо еще раз большое, Надо попрактиковаться, чтобы отложилось в памяти.